# How to have inputs and a label on the same line in HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a table row that is getting appended to a table via AJAX/JQuery. The row is supposed to have some text that describes what a "category" is and then two buttons (input tags) that would carry out a specific action when clicked. It works except for the fact that I can not get the text to be formatted the way I want it. I want the buttons and text to be on the same line on the row with the text on the left-hand side.

If I put the text in the  then it creates its own line and the buttons are rendered below the label. If I put the text in a  then everything is on the same line but the text is to the right of the buttons rather than the left. I have also tried many styling techniques like display: inline-block and vertical-align: top all to no avail.

```
$('#listOptionsTable').append('< tr >< td >' + '<text>' + result.Value + '</text>' + "< input type='button' class='btn' id='addButton' onclick='addPopulateCategoryTable(" + result.SpecListOptionID + ")' value='Add To Category(s)' />" + "< input type='button' class='btn' id='deleteButton' onclick='deletePopulateCategoryTable(" + result.SpecListOptionID + ")' value='Delete From Category(s)' />" + '< /td >< /tr >');
```

How can I get it to all be on the same line with the text to the left followed by the two buttons directly after?

EDIT: Here is my table with the CSS defined. It's a pretty simple table, nothing too fancy:

```
< table id="listOptionsTable" style="background-color:#F0F0F0;" >< /table >
```

Comment: Please format your question!

Comment: Yes this is my first post here. I simply followed the "guided" post creation tool and what you see is what came out. For future reference, how do I format code in that easily-readable box?

Comment: The HTML layout is dependent on both your CSS and the size of your table (as TD cells will wrap contents). You need to put your CSS into the question as well, so people can help.

Comment: Also I don't think `<text></text>` is a valid HTML tag. Do you mean a `<label></label>` tag?

Comment: Yes I did use label and that's where I had the issue of it creating it's own line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TD cells will collapse and wrap everything inside of them, as they can.

To prevent that, set a width on the TD tags with CSS:

```
<style>
#listOptionsTable td {width: 300px}
</style>
```

Or whatever width you want. Without that, the width will be auto, and will shrink down as it sees fit while causing your objects to wrap.

Comment: Widening the td to 600px, which is much larger than the buttons, seems to have had no effect and it still wraps into its own line.

Comment: SOLVED: I simply put the label in a separate td from the buttons but in the same row and it worked.